# Bool variable filtering varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I want to filter by the function they have.

For instance, my database is:

```
Name   | Teamleader | Coordinator | Manager | Function
-------------------------------------------------------
Tony   |   Arthur   |   George    |  Mary   |  Sales
Trisha |   Hannah   |   Hannah    | Andrew  | Associate
```

I want to filter by their function, but I wanted it to be just a simple boolean, where if my boolean variable `@assoc = 1` then it would only show associates, and if `@assoc = 0` then it wouldn't show associates.

I'm trying this query, but I get erros in the equals `Incorrect syntax near '='.` and in FROM `Incorrect syntax near 'from'. Expecting CONVERSATION.`

```
declare @assoc BIT = 1

set @assoc = (select case @assoc = 1 THEN u_function = 'associate' ELSE u_function != 'associate' END from cm3)
```

Comment: should be `CASE WHEN @assoc = 1`

Comment: I've tried that but it now gives me an error at the `function` where it says `Invalid column name 'function'`

Comment: Or `CASE @Assoc WHEN 1 THEN...`

Comment: `FUNCTION` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) anyway, so I actually expect the error "Incorrect syntax near keyword 'FUNCTION'." You should avoid giving object's name that are reserved keywords.

Comment: It gives me the same error

Comment: Then your table, `cm3`, doesn't have a column `function`, @pauLo_0liveira (though you would have to refer to it as `[function]`, due to the aforementioned keyword).

Comment: @Larnu function i've translated the column names so it would be easier to explain, the real column name is u_function, I'm going to update it so it won't confuse anyone else

Comment: Common mistake - you are treating `case` as [flow control] statement, but you can only use it as expression (and compare its result to something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if my boolean variable @assoc = 1 then it would only show associates, and if @assoc = 0 then it wouldn't show associates.

You seem to want a query with a where clause based on the @assoc variable:

```
select *
from cm3
where (@assoc = 1 and u_function = 'Associate')
   or (@assoc = 0 and u_function <> 'Associate');
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want, thank you! My concern is if with a big database it will be slow to execute the query.

Comment: I don't expect this to get very slow. The whole table will get read sequentially, which is not a big deal, as the query is supposed to return many of its rows anyway. If that table contained millions of rows, would you want to select millions of rows or wouldn't you rather add some restriction to the query? It is not the assoc restriction that would make the query slow, but the lack of a more restrictive clause.

Answer (score 0):

1. function is a reserved keyword.
2. to assign the values to @assoc, I recommend this:

```
DECLARE @assoc BIT = 1
    
    SELECT @assoc = CASE 
            WHEN pfunction = 'Associate'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
    FROM cm3
    
    SELECT @assoc
```

SCRIPT USED TO TEST THE RESULT IS:

```
CREATE TABLE cm3 (
    name VARCHAR(20)
    ,teamleader VARCHAR(20)
    ,coordinator VARCHAR(20)
    ,manager VARCHAR(20)
    ,pfunction VARCHAR(20)
    )

INSERT INTO cm3
VALUES (
    'Tony'
    ,'Arthur'
    ,'George'
    ,'Mary'
    ,'Sales'
    )
    ,(
    'Trisha '
    ,'Hannah   '
    ,'Hannah   '
    ,'Andrew  '
    ,'Associate'
    )

DECLARE @assoc BIT = 1

SELECT @assoc = CASE 
        WHEN pfunction = 'Associate'
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
FROM cm3

SELECT @assoc

DROP TABLE cm3
```

the result is `1`

Comment: This would give the error "Invalid column name 'pfunction'" if the OP truly *did* have a column named `function` though.

Comment: This removed the errors, but I wanted to return the function instead of the boolean variable.

Comment: @pauLo_0liveira try use [function]